# Diff between Declaring arrayList polymorphically and normally?

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

is there's any difference between declaring an arrayList polymorphically like that:

```
List<Integer> iL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and the normal style like that:

```
ArrayList<String> stuff = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a difference

with

```
List<Integer> iL ;
```

You could do

```
iL = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and also

```
iL = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Advantages:

You could refer to any other Object that **is a** `List`

---

**Also See**

- [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: I find this particular argument a bit empty. If I write `final List<X> l = new ArrayList<X>` then I'm obviously not going to refer to anything else but an `ArrayList`. Using `ArrayList` as a public method's param or return value, that **is** a mortal sin.

Comment: @Marko yes it makes sense if it is final but generally its not, thats where we gain the advantage of substitution

Comment: Yes, but 90% of all local vars (especially collection-typed ones) that you have ever seen are final by nature, just nobody bothers to put `final` on them.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally advised to use the first declaration. It allows to change the implementation of the list easily, only by changing the line with the instantiation. Also it shows your intent that you are not using any additional functionality provided by `ArrayList`.

There is some performance cost when you use the interface, but on modern VMs it should be barely noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In the second case, `stuff` can only ever be an ArrayList. In the first, `iL` can be an instance of any class that implements the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And it goes beyond just the "coding style" issue the other answers are harping on about...

[`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has more methods than the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface provides (eg [`trimToSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29)), so declaring the variable as an `ArrayList` gives you access to those methods.

In general, unless you need access to those special methods, it is better to declare it as a `List`, following the pattern of declaring the abstract class in preference to the concrete (allowing you to swap implementations at will, for example using a `LinkedList` instead)

Answer (score 1):

u only have access to list functions etc. of it is list.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all these standard answers "program to the interface" etc., writing `ArrayList` where you could've written `List` is just plain ugly, so you'd better have a reason to do it -- and 99% of the time there won't be any.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences when using the interface in the declaration:

- Denotes what's minimally important. If you need specific methods available only in the concrete subclass, declare it as such.
- Allows you to swap in a different implementation (`LinkedList` or `CopyOnWriteList`) with minimal changes.
- *Tiny* performance penalty due to polymorphism.

Given the above, declare method parameter and return types using the interface to hide unimportant implementation details and minimize limitations. Declare local variables using the actual class only when performance is *ultra-critical* or if you need the additional methods it provides. If you choose a different concrete class later, you'll need to change the call to the constructor which will likely be on the same line as the declaration.